# How to use onclick and push state to props at one time ? i have push is undef error

Tags: reactjs

```
changeRoutePath = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onClose();
    this.props.history.push('/company/orgStructure');
};
<Link
                to={{
                    pathname: '/company/orgStructure',
                    state: {
                        fromNotifications: true
                    }
                }}
                onClick={(e) => this.changeRoutePath(e)}>
                Prevent
            </Link>
```

I  have error Uncaught `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

I have a import of the Link

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
```

Need to go on /company/orgStructure page and take some info in state! How to do it?
If i use just link without onclick i cant use this.props.onClose for close modal. How to push info and go to orgStructure?

`bgClose: false
className: ""
container: true
employeeCode: "00-005424"
escClose: false
onClose: ƒ ()
open: true
showModalEmployeeShortProfile: ƒ ()
stack: true
template: null
title: "Профиль сотрудника"
width: 960`
console.log(this.props);

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong with your code...have a look at the answer I've provided

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the error you're getting is from your `changeRoutePath` function. The `history` object isn't defined in the `props` for that component and that's probably because your component is probably not rendered through a `Route` component like this.

```
<Route path="/your-path" component={YourComponent} />
```

If it isn't, you can wrap your component with the `WithRouter` HOC from `react-router`.

```
import { WithRouter } from "react-router";

// rest of code...

export default WithRouter(YourComponent);
```

Secondly, you don't need to add an `onClick` function to the `Link` component.

You can easily do this...

```
changeRoutePath = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.onClose();
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/company/orgStructure'),
    state: {
      fromNotifications: true
    }
  });
};
```

Then instead of a `Link`, you can do this

```
<a href="#" onClick={e => this.changeRoutePath(e)}>Prevent</a>
```

Comment: how is your component being rendered from the route?

Comment: Is your component rendered from inside another component or from a `Route` component?

Comment: is your component the `AutoComplete` component?

Comment: what do you get when you do `console.log(this.props)` in your `render` function?

Comment: How to plus this.props.history in my this.props?